# publish a small webpage on a facebook page

Tags: facebook, html

My company has developed two pages that we would like to publish on a clients facebookpage. These pages are hosted at my company, and are basic webpages but with a width of 520 pixels with facebook in mind.

I have created two apps in the facebook developer section, and I have filled in my url there and set it to `publish as a page tab`. I also set the namespace to a unique name and uploaded an icon.

when I'm looking at the app, I can't find a button like `publish it on a profile page`, and when I'm looking at client's facebook page (where I have been made an admin of), I can go to the apps but not `browse` to a custom made one to link mine to the facebook page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this link to add the tab to your (client's) page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOURAPPID&next=YOURDOMAIN
```

The Facebook documentation can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: no problem, welcome to Stack Overflow. If my answer solved your question then you can consider accepting it so that it is marked as closed.